# How can I update an excel file in sharepoint after read?

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, openpyxl, office365api

Originally I want to use data in one excel file to update data in another excel file in sharepoint, while is split 3 steps.

1. implemented read excel file in sharepoint site.
2. implement writing changes to the excel file in sharepoint site.
3. need to implement reading from an excel and get data then use data to update anther excel.(not in the code below)

I know I should use Office365 API to read excel file in sharepoint.   When I want to use openpyxl to do wb.save (), I got error:OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument. I don't know how to put absolute web url in save(). This is different with saving an excel in local drive. frustrated, appreciate it.

```
SP_SITE_URL ='https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName'
relative_url = "/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/FolderName"


# 1. Create a ClientContext object and use the user’s credentials for authentication 
ctx = ClientContext(SP_SITE_URL).with_user_credentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD) 
ClientFolder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(relative_url)
ctx.load(ClientFolder)
ctx.execute_query()

#if you want to get the files in the folder        
files = ClientFolder.files
print(files)
ctx.load(files)
ctx.execute_query()

newest_file_url = ''
for myfile in files:
    
    if myfile.properties["Name"] == 'Filename.xlsx':
        newest_file_url = myfile.properties["ServerRelativeUrl"]
# Get Excel File by newest_file_url identified above
response= File.open_binary(ctx, newest_file_url)
    # save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)  # set file object to start

# load Excel file from BytesIO stream
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(bytes_file_obj)
worksheet= wb['Sheet1'] 

# updates
row_count = worksheet.max_row
col_count = worksheet.max_column 
for i in range(2,row_count+1):
    for j in range(4,col_count + 1):
        cellref=worksheet.cell(i, j)
        cellref.value=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# save update to the file
wb.save('https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/SiteName/Shared%20Documents/FolderName/Filename.xlsx?d=xxxxx&csf=1&web=1&e=xxx')
```

Comment: Save the file locally and use something else to upload it to Sharepoint.

Comment: @CharlieClark, thx, that's one option, but it's like replacing a file completely, actually the target file was a sheet inside a excel, that file also has other sheets, if I do so, may be inefficient?

Comment: Zipfiles can't be edited in place so you're always replacing them.